# Date under SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i would like to extract all "COMPANY_CODE" using this request with oracle

```
SELECT COMPANY_CODE from "CUSTOM_LIFETIME_VALUE_31DEC20" 
WHERE to_date(LEASE_START2,'yyyy-MM-dd') > to_date(2020-01-01, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

but i get this error :

```
 non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Any idea please to help me?
thanks

Comment: `2020-01-01` is an arithmetic expression yielding `2018`. You forgot to put quotes around it.

Comment: And what is the data type of  LEASE_START2 ?  If it is a DATE then you should not be applying to_date to it.  And if it is _not_ of type DATE, then you have a serious design flaw.  TO_DATE converts a _string_ representation of a date to a DATE type.  So if LEASE_START2 is already a DATE, you are forcing oracle to first apply (under the covers) a to_char to it, so that it can then be fed to to_date to convert it back to a date, where it started.  These implied converstions are fraught with potential for errors.  See https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: @stickybit - that is indeed one mistake, but it would throw a different error - "input value not long enough for date format". There must be other mistakes as well - although it is strange that that error (the one I mentioned) is not the first one to be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:-
WHERE to_date(LEASE_START2,'yyyy-MM-dd') > to_date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: it was this` LEASE_START2 > to_date('2020-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd')`  Thanks

Comment: @butter - so, do you understand **exactly** how that error was thrown? Ed Stevens explained it in his Comment under your post. Wondering if Preeti could. Anyway: `LEASE_START2` is already a date. You call `to_date()` on it but that expects a string. Oracle converts it using your `nls_date_format` by default, which is probably `dd-MON-rr` or similar - using something like `'JAN'` for months. When you try to convert back to date with the model `'yyyy-MM-dd'`, Oracle finds `'JAN'` where it expects a number (`'MM'` means monht **number**, not name) - so you get that error.

Comment: @butter - In any case, I don't see how **this** solution (from a poster different from Ed Stevens) is the one that helped you find the correct answer. There is nothing in **this** solution pointing you in the right direction.